# Multiply Sparse Matrices stored as lists C++ preferred

Tags: c++, math, sparse-matrix

I currently have implemented a basic algorithm for multiplying two sparse matrices.

In my implementation a sparse matrix has a back-bone of rows and then a list of nodes with their column attached.

I currently go through the rows and columns of the new matrix, and increment k to get all the row and columns multiplied together.

I then do a slight optimization only accessing the non-zero elements of matrix of the row in matrix A (A*B = C).

But currently the big slow down is having to get the correct column in B. ie. A(i, k) * B(k, j). B(k, j) being super expensive as you have to iterate each time until you get column j to match.

This works but I was wondering if I could make it any faster.

Thanks.

PS: most of the posts I have seen until now focus on implementation specific, I would much prefer an algorithm, c++ code being a bonus.

I also tried saving the empty columns ahead of time by traversing Matrix B, but I am not sure if that significantly made it faster.

Comment: Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted. Repeated low-quality questions may result in a temporary ban from asking new questions.

Comment: Is this matrix multiplication?  Modules like the Python `scipy.sparse` do this with the Compressed Row format (CSR), and do it in two steps.  The first determines the number of nonzero elements in the resulting matrix, and the second fills in those values.  The reference is some math paper from the 1990s (probably first implemented in Fortran).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a nice algo for this which uses every element it iterates over.
I would say your algo is O(n^3) mult * ~n for accessing each jth member every time, so roughly O(n^4).

This algo is < O(n^3).

```
    A = [
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 2, 0, 4],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            ]
    B = [
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
                [0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
                [0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            ]
```

The algo works such,

1. Iterate through the rows of A, if the row is empty, skip it
2. For that column, (0, 1) = 1, so check if row 1 of B is empty, if not, iterate through it (that is the only things that 1 will interact with)
3. For each node in row ai(k) column of B (in this case 1), multiply the value of the node with the value of the node in A, and add it to the result matrix
   -> in our case that would be (0, 1) * (1, 3) = 1 * 2 = 2, so add 2 to the result matrix at (0, 3)

Note:
Each of the m rows, n cols, and k (row-col match) form n^3, but in Sparse Matrices, there are much fewer that you have to iterate over, because of low density.

We can skip over 0 rows reducing m, we can skip over "0" row values reducing k, and we can skip over some 0 columns making k smaller again. There is no real way to reduce n in this algorithm.

In the end, our O(m*n*k) ie O(n^3) has a much smaller coefficient say O(1/100 * m*n*k) as you are using fewer of those elements.

Comment: Thank you, haven't implemented it yet, but will tell you when I do!